# vscode extension how to custom text-editor save action

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

We need to build a plugin on vscode that edits simple text data returned from ajax, and I want to send the data back to the backend when triggering a save with Ctrl+S, instead of saving it to a local file.

current sample code;

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";

// ...
const { siteId, codeId } = dualId;
const codeBlock = await siteService.getCodeData(siteId, codeId);
const textDocument = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
  language: "typescript",
  content: codeBlock.body
});
// I hope custom editor save action, not save in local file
```

The text editor's save operation sends an ajax request back to the server, rather than saving to a local file, and I'd like to be able to do this without creating a webview view.